# Django&REST-framework architecture

Tags: django, architecture, django-rest-framework

Hello I am tasked with translating a current Excel tool to a web application. I decided to use Python and Django. Lately I studied the Django REST framework. I have the following related questions.

Is it for such an application a good idea to first write a web REST API so that I
firstly only need to focus on the backbone of the web application. I.e. implement the PUT, POST, GET and DELETE methods and the Django models.
The second step would be to implement the user interface... But if this is a valid method how can I reuse the REST views??? I followed the REST tutorials, but they don't show how to build a nice slick user-interface on top of the REST API. 
Since REST views inherit from Django, I think it's maybe not such a good idea to write a Django view which inherits from a REST Apiview? Or can I directly use an API endpoint in a template. If so where can I get some nice examples?

Comment: REST views are meant for API interfaces. Django Rest Framework does [come with an HTML interface](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/) you may use.

Comment: Django Rest Framework has nothing to do with UI; it help's you build a REST API for you app. If you application is very simple, just using Django views and template rendering may be sufficient. If your application starts becoming more and more complex in the future, you can introduce Django Rest Framework then and consider a separate framework for the front end (like Angular) that talks to your REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing the back-end separately using **Django REST Framework** is a great idea.

There is a strong architecture based on **the idea of decoupling the back-end from the front-end**. After you finish the project's backbone, as you are calling it, you can start creating you front-end but your don't have to use Django template rendering in that case.

You can take the pros of using REST APIs and you can use one of the good front-end frameworks or libraries as **Angular** and **React.js**.
Another advantage of this that the same API can work with mobile development and so on.

So you develop one back-end and multiple front-ends depends on your need.

Also you can read a discussion about your question on Quora: https://www.quora.com/Why-does-it-make-sense-to-separate-front-end-from-back-end

Comment: Ok thanks, so seems to be some merit in using the REST framework to build the backend. But since I'm a beginner (and lazy ;). Is there an elegant way to implement the front end using the Django and REST framework? Can I use Django views which extend the REST API-views. Or do I need to use API endpoints? Some nice examples would be helpfull.

Comment: If you are not willing to use a separate front-end or a mobile app in the future, then what is the benefit of using Django REST framework in the first place?

Comment: That's a good point, I'm now trying to mainly just use Django so as to make something tangible as soon as possible. And it should be possible to use the REST-framework to create an API endpoint which I can use to populate one (or more) [Chartjs graphs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4Vmm3yZPgc).